# Errors while executing Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've been struggling to work out why my procedure isn't working for a while. So can anyone help me, Sorry I'm still very new to sql. It it should lookup the course_number based on the course name. if it does not find a match, it defaults the course number to ****. it then inserts a new record into the `student_course` table. Here is a copy of the database I'm using https://www.dropbox.com/s/cmqmzggiygxbkth/dissertation_database.txt
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hm90jga9zsaawnt/course_procedure.txt

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE upda_course
 ( name IN VARCHAR2 )   
IS
   course_id VARCHAR2;
   cursor c1 is
   SELECT course_id
FROM courses
    WHERE name = name;
BEGIN
   open c1;
   fetch c1 into course_id;
   if c1%notfound then
      course_id := 9999;
   end if;

   INSERT INTO course_modules
   ( course_id, module_id
     )
   VALUES
   ( name,
     course_id );

   commit;

   close c1;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END upda_course;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
EXECUTE upda_course('business computing systems');
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Error Displayed when Executed

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: An error was encountered - -6502 -ERROR- ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric
or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "INS2014_106.UPDA_COURSE", line 29
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: You did not specify the input paramter. Specify a value for input paramter and execute again

Comment: `WHERE name = name;` your column name is same as variable name? May be you  would have masked the code. But Just want to let you know, It's column the oracle will refer, when there's a conflict! And In your insert, you insert `NUMBER` into a `VARCHAR`/`CHAR` field..??!! or vice versa.. And hence this error

Comment: can you show your table structure??

Comment: `CREATE TABLE courses(
course_id VARCHAR2(8),
name VARCHAR2(50),
created date);`

Comment: Show the schema of your course_module table

Comment: Given that there are only 29 source lines in UPDA_COURSE I find it difficult to diagnose what's wrong in line 33. Apparently UPDA_COURSE has changed since you first included it in your question. Please edit your question and put in the version of UPDA_COURSE which corresponds to the error message you posted. Thanks.

Comment: I have linked all the database files that I have used and updated all the code to the current version I'm using

Comment: course_id is declared as varchar2, but you assigned 9999 to it. Assign as below : course_id := '9999';

Answer (score 0):

Please try,

Procedure is taking a parameter(Name) as an input:

```
EXECUTE upda_course 'somename';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EXECUTE upda_course('some course');
```

Comment: Thank you I tried that and I got this error ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: An error was encountered - -6502 -ERROR- ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric
or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "INS2014_32.UPDA_COURSE", line 33
ORA-06512: at line 1                          EXECUTE upda_course('business computing systems');
BEGIN upda_course('business computing systems'); END;

Comment: course_id Is a varchar(I understand as you are passing a parameter as varchar), where as

cursor c1 is
 SELECT course_id
 FROM courses
 WHERE name = name;

while fetching a value from above cursor you are fetching into a numeric value. :)

Answer (score 0):

Specify the input value for input parameter

```
EXECUTE upda_course 'somename';
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive `course_id` column in `course_modules` table is also a number . You are trying to insert a varchar2 to the column which is `Number` Hence the error. Also use your input variable as something like `v_name`as  your query below will return all rows from the table as variable name is same as column name. Same with `course_id` variable inside the procedure.

```
SELECT course_id
FROM courses
    WHERE name = name;
```

Comment: Its only when I execute that it is failing so could that still mean its an issue with my code when creating the procedure

Comment: yes. It will not give compilition error. Error will occur at run time.

Comment: I've checked the creates and both my ids are stored as VARCHAR2